# MVC DisplayTemplates Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, display-templates

I have a following problem: I downloaded a Sql2Tree Solution. here is the link: http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Sql2Tree.zip

And  There whole tree structure wrods just fine.
I did the same thing in my solution, but I have sql DB instewad of sdf but it does not make any difference, does it?
But if I create DisplayTemplates folder in "Shared" then the cshtml file from DisplayTemplates is not beeing seen.
Why? What should I do to make it work?

My solution is seriously the same, but I have noticed that in the Sql2Tree Solution there is no App_Start folder and some more things.

Comment: No code describing the problem, link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Problem Solved- All I had to do was to change the name in Shared/DisplayTemplates from TreeNodes.cshtml to TreeNode.cshtml. It is important in DisplayTemplates to names of the cshtml files be the same as the reference to them ;d.